# Mixing DirectX and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, directx

I want to be able to render into an OpenGL render window using DirectX. This is because the features i'm after are only supported in DirectX.

I have heard it is possible to do this a few years ago and i'm hoping it should still be possible.

I'd imagine it will involve pointing DirectX to the correct part of VRAM and the correct depth buffer.

Also a tutorial or simply an explanation would be extremely useful.

Comment: Why do you need to output it into OpenGL? If DirectX is available why not just stick with the DX renderer?

Comment: Mainly because I require the windows OpenGL commands to correctly render the OpenGL render surface in a windows child window.

Comment: "This is because the features i'm after are only supported in Direct X." And what features are those? I know of very few D3D features that are not also available under OpenGL.

Comment: ... Every Direct3D feature CAN be implemented in OpenGL. Just it can get tricky to do it properly.

Answer (score 3):

At least NVIDIA has the [NV_DX_interop extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/DX_interop.txt), which let's you use Direct3D 9 buffers/textures/surfaces directly as OpenGL buffers/textures/renderbuffers (therefore being the other way around). But I don't have any experience with this and I don't know if it is widely supported or actually works any good.

It would be more interresting which features you think are only available in Direct3D. Maybe we can show you how to achieve it with OpenGL, as there are not many features (if any) that are available in Direct3D and not in OpenGL. Although if you got an ATI card, being available and actually working correctly may sometimes be two seperate things.

Comment: Note that even that interop does not allow you to render with both APIs to the _same_ window. If you have different windows, or off-screen rendering contexts, then you can use this. But not to the same surface.

Comment: You can render via OpenGL in one offscreen surface, with DirectX in another, then copy and combine their textures.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing OpenGL and Direct3D will not work, and AFAIK it never used to. May I ask, which features of Direct3D you require, that OpenGL doesn't offer?

Answer (score 0):

You can. At least for nVIDIA! Check NV_DX_interop. But however, EVERY DirectX feature is supported in OpenGL as OpenGL is more RAW / Low level than DirectX! Just the way it is implemented may be different. Again, tell us WHICH feature of DirectX you want and I can tell you hints how to reimplement it.

Answer (score 0):

One specific example of a difference between OpenGL and Direct3D, which is something I am researching myself, is that in DirectShow (a subset of Direct3D), there are video capture filters for my Panasonic DVCPRO-HD based cameras.  So the live streams collected via that API, I would like to use as inputs into OpenGL libraries.  One such library is OpenFrameWorks, which is OpenGL based.  I am looking to see how efficient I can make this transfer.  The existing OpenFrameWorks Video API uses a slightly older and deprecated DirectShow API, and uses a brute force strategy for getting pixels from DirectShow over to OpenFrameWorks.